# Handling onDismissed without having items within a List

Tags: dart, flutter, dismissible

I am using the Dismissible widget for doing some tinder-like swiping in my application. This means that i am essentially swiping away my whole widget. This mean I have no ListView builder with the items getting dismissed. How do I need to handle the onDismissed without putting all my items into a list beforehand?

I already tried just using a fake list, where I give it an ID, and just remove that. But it doesn't seem to do anything, this code can be seen below.

```
  static var uuid = new Uuid();
  final dismissRemover = List<String>.generate(50, (i) => "item: '$uuid'");

 body: Dismissible(
        key: new Key(dismissRemover[0]),
        background: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.thumb_down,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 150.0,
          ),
        ),
        secondaryBackground: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.thumb_up,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 150.0,
          ),
        ),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
            setState(() {
              _newPolitician.performPolitician(true, context, item[_politicianNo]['id'], _collectionName);
              dismissRemover.removeAt(0);
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _newPolitician.performPolitician(false, context, item[_politicianNo]['id'], _collectionName);
              dismissRemover.removeAt(0);
            });
          }
        },
```

Have you any idea how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want tinder like card swipe UI, you can get some code ready from these projects use them:

1. [Card swipe v1](https://startflutter.com/themes/flutter-card-swipe/)
2. [Card swipe v2](https://startflutter.com/themes/542/)

**Edited:**
Your requirement is that

1. you want card swiping.
2. You want animation that is provided by Dismissible.
3. You don't want List and want a tinder-like UI.

Solution use stack like this :

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Dismissible(
      key: Key('Card'),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0), 
          child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Dismissible(
      key: Key('Card 1'),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
        child: Icon(Icons.accessibility),
      ),
    ),
  ),
],
)
```

(note the above code is dirty and it is just to give you an idea to use the stack for your required UI)
[image]

Comment: I am not a fan of those, I like the simple sideswipe that dismissible provides me with. But thank you.